# How to get unlabeled data by BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
  Contents
  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">
   Google what time is it
  </a>
  <br/>
  It's 4:38.
  <br/>
  2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM
 </div>]
```

In the code above, I want to extract the answer ("It's 4:38") and the timestamp. For the question, I used

> for link in soup.find_all('a'): Questions.append(link.text);

but I couldn't do the same with the answers and timestamp. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the text you want is a descendant of the `div` element. You can also see that it immediately follows the first `br` element that is such a descendant. Then one way to find it is simply to iterate through the descendants of the `div` looking for that `br`. When you see that take the next item.

Here's how it will play out.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('sumin.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> div = soup.find('div')
>>> for element in div.descendants:
...     element.name, element
...     
(None, '\n  Contents\n  ')
('a', <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">
   Google what time is it
  </a>)
(None, '\n   Google what time is it\n  ')
(None, '\n')
('br', <br/>)
(None, "\n  It's 4:38.\n  ")
('br', <br/>)
(None, '\n  2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM\n ')
```

Notice that elements such as `br` have the `name` property but navigable strings do not (this property is None).

Answer (score 0):

> How to get unlabeled data

Actually, it is not unlabeled. The text you want is located inside the `<div>` tag. To get that text you can check if the text is `NavigableString`.

If you check the type of each content,

```
Contents  #<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>

<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">
   Google what time is it
</a>           #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

#<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
<br/>   #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

  It's 4:38.    #<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
<br/>  #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

  2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM      #<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Code:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
>>> html = '''<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
...   Contents
...   <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">
...    Google what time is it
...   </a>
...   <br/>
...   It's 4:38.
...   <br/>
...   2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM
...  </div>'''    
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> div = soup.find('div', class_='content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1')
>>> contents = [x.strip() for x in div.contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)]
>>> contents
['Contents', '', "It's 4:38.", '2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM']
```

From this, you can understand what `NavigableString` is. Now, to get the date and time you can simply join the last 2 elements of the list.

```
>>> ' '.join(contents[-2:])
"It's 4:38. 2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">\n  Contents\n  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">\n   Google what time is it\n  </a>\n  <br/>\n  It\'s 4:38.\n  <br/>\n  2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM\n </div>'

s = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")

>>> s.find("br").findNext("br").next
'\n  2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM\n '
>>> s.find("br").next
"\n  It's 4:38.\n  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in combo with [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser:

```py
soup.select_one('.YwPhnf').text
# 09:06
```

Or you can use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#strings-and-stripped-strings), but it's not as pretty as using `CSS` selectors:

```py
html = '''
<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
Contents
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+what+time+is+it">
  Google what time is it
</a>
<br/>
It's 4:38.
<br/>
2018. 2. 5. 5:38:41 PM
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# returns a generator object 
current_time = list(soup.select_one('.content-cell').stripped_strings)[2]
print(current_time)

# It's 4:38.
```

---

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "what time it is",  # query
  "gl": "us",              # country to search from
  "hl": "en"               # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

current_time = soup.select_one('.YwPhnf').text
current_date = soup.select_one('.KfQeJ:nth-child(1)').text
print(f'{current_time}\n{current_date}')

# 2:11 AM
# September 11, 2021
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to get the data you want from the structured JSON, rather than figuring out to extract things and maintain the parser over time if something won't work correctly because of some changes in the HTML.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "what time it is",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['answer_box']['result'])

# 2:07 AM
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.